# Display element not found and add it to the list in angular2

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

In my Heroes app, I have an input text that checks the service if the hero is present or not. If present, it displays it in a drop down.
What I want is to display the hero name if it is not present and also add a button to add the hero to the the array.

My hero-search.component.html

```
<div id="search-component">
  <h4>Hero Search</h4>
  <input #searchBox id="search-box" (keyup)="search(searchBox.value)" />
  <div>
    <div *ngIf = "heroes"> // this div is not working 
      no element found
    </div>
    <div *ngFor="let hero of heroes | async"
         (click)="gotoDetail(hero)" class="search-result" >
      {{hero.name}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

my hero-search.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router }            from '@angular/router';
import { Observable }        from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject }           from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { HeroSearchService } from './hero-search.service';
import { Hero } from './hero';
@Component({
  selector: 'hero-search',
  templateUrl: 'hero-search.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ 'hero-search.component.css' ],
})
export class HeroSearchComponent implements OnInit {
  heroes: Observable<Hero[]>;
  private searchTerms = new Subject<string>();
  constructor(
    private heroSearchService: HeroSearchService,
    private router: Router) {}
  // Push a search term into the observable stream.
  search(term: string): void {
    this.searchTerms.next(term);
    console.log("Heroes"+this.heroes);
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.heroes = this.searchTerms
      .debounceTime(300)        // wait for 300ms pause in events
      .distinctUntilChanged()   // ignore if next search term is same as previous
      .switchMap(term => term   // switch to new observable each time
        // return the http search observable
        ? this.heroSearchService.search(term)
        // or the observable of empty heroes if no search term
        : Observable.of<Hero[]>([]))
      .catch(error => {
        // TODO: real error handling
        console.log(error);
        return Observable.of<Hero[]>([]);
      });
  }
  gotoDetail(hero: Hero): void {
    let link = ['/detail', hero.id];
    this.router.navigate(link);
  }
}
```

The *ngIf is not working as well as adding a button to add the hero back to array.

The div is always there in the page no matter the heroes array is populated.

Please help. I am new to angular 2.

Answer (score 0):

`heroes` is `Ovservable<Hero[]>` and as I see you want to display the `div` in question only when the array is empty. So your condition should be `*ngIf="(heroes | async)?.length == 0"`. In the current implementation the div always shows up because `*ngIf` evaluates to `true`  as `heroes` has a value, i.e.  it's **not** `undefined`.

Comment: it works thanks , but can i ask why we are using async and also after inputing a non existing hero and then deleting it from the input box the data persists means the *ngIf still shows  as no element found is persisting

Comment: We're using `async` because `heroes` isn't just an array but Observable of array. `async` is a pipe which in fact serves as `subscribe`. It retrieves the value from the observable. To your second question: if the hero is not existant then the array will stay empty and therefore the message shows up.